# Change paragraph attribute to input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried following code in which I am trying to change paragraph tag to input fields through jquery on button click. I want my values to retain in the textbox when I click the button. Unfortunately, it isn't working! Here I have tried it with just name field. Any suggestions please.

**code**

```
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Address Book</h3>
            <p>Default delivery address</p>
            <?php
            $em=$_SESSION['login_email'];
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers where email='$em'" );
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            ?>
            <h5>Name:</h5><p  class="name" id="name"><?= $row['name'] ?></p>
            <h5>Email:</h5><p class="mail"><?= $row['email'] ?></p>
            <h5>Telephone:</h5><p class="tele"><?= $row['phone'] ?></p>
            <h5>Address:</h5><p class="addres"><?= $row['address'] ?></p>
             <h5>City:</h5><p class="city"><?= $row['city'] ?></p>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <input type="button" id="update" value="Update Address" >
        </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#update').click(function()

            var input = $("<input>", { val: $(this).text(),type: "text" });
            $('#name').replaceWith(input);
            input.select();
        });
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: A code snippet or jsfiddle would be nice :)

Comment: @www139 here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/95tajxec/  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, bar two errors. Firstly, you're missing a `{` after the `click` handler function definition. Secondly, `this` within the `#update` click handler refers to the `button` element, yet you're trying to read the `val()` of the `#name` input, so you need to change the selector. With that in mind, try this:

```
$('#update').click(function() {
    var $name = $('#name');
    var $input = $("<input>", { 
        val: $name.text(),
        type: "text"
    });
    $name.replaceWith($input);
    $input.select();
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/knygbsmo/)

I would also be wary of having duplicated `id` attributes in your page as you are defining the elements in a loop. Should there be multiple rows returned from your query, then you will have multiple elements with the same `id` in the document which will lead to possible errors as the HTML will be invalid.